# How to download all English books from Gutenberg?

Tags: project-gutenberg

I need to download all Gutenberg ebooks, in plain text format (not html)
and only in English language.

Anyone has suggestions how to download them all from the Gutenberg server?

I need them to make a linguistic research.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [Information About Robot Access to our Pages](https://www.gutenberg.org/policy/robot_access.html):

> **The Project Gutenberg website is intended for human users only.** Any perceived use of automated tools to access the Project Gutenberg website will result in a temporary or permanent block of your IP address. The only exceptions to this rule are below.
>
> - [How to Get All Ebook Files](https://www.gutenberg.org/policy/robot_access.html#how-to-get-all-ebook-files)
> - [How to Get Certain Ebook Files](https://www.gutenberg.org/policy/robot_access.html#how-to-get-certain-ebook-files)
> - [How to Mirror Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/policy/robot_access.html#how-to-mirror-project-gutenberg)
> - [How to Get Catalog Data](https://www.gutenberg.org/policy/robot_access.html#how-to-get-catalog-data)

The page in the links above give you examples to use `wget`. So, I'd quess:

```
wget -w 2 -m -H http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?filetypes[]=txt&langs[]=en
```

Aside, back in February 2011 when this answer was posted, and up to October 2011, [its wiki said](https://web.archive.org/web/20111006105211/http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Information_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages):

> Robot access to our site should be left as last resource, when everything else has failed. Also, remember that the Project Gutenberg web site is copyrighted.
>
> [...] You can get all our eBooks in zipped files by pointing your robot at
> http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest
>
> [...]  Unpacking the zip files will produce another 70,000 files.
>
> This is an example of how to get all files using `wget`:
>
> ```
> wget -w 2 -m http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest
> ```
>
> [...]  If you want only some types of files say:
>
> ```
> wget -w 2 -m http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?filetypes[]=txt
> ```
>
> [...] If you want only files in a given language say:
>
> ```
> wget -w 2 -m http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?langs[]=de
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to tell wget to limit the number of files that it downloads while crawling (e.g. first 100 text files it encounters)?

Comment: Also, when we have a number of links in a text file (absolute uri, say "http://gutenberg.org/files/1.zip, http://gutenberg.org/files/2.zip", what parameter is used to provide such a text file as a number of download links to WGET?

Comment: @rohanbk, you can see what will be downloaded by browsing the URL itself, like http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?filetypes[]=txt&langs[]=en This shows it's actually paginated, but the number of files per page is not constant. (Maybe based on size?) So, to NOT recurse, according to [the wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download), you might try `--level=0`. But I guess you better allow to abort and restart: try `--level 9999 --no-clobber`, which will skip files you already have (assuming you're still in the same folder on disk).

Comment: @EugeneP, see `--input-file` [in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options).

Comment: @Arjan Is there a way to specify offset at the start of download? My downloading interrupted due to some reasons and now wget has started checking files from the first page. I had used `-c` option, but still. I gave `offset=xxx` in the URL to be mirrored but still it is downloading from first page.

Comment: Nope, I don't know, @user13107. I guess what you did (both `-c` and `offset`, or even just only `offset`) should do the trick. Are you 100% sure the URL with `offset` is correct?

Comment: @Arjan yes, the URL is correct, in fact, it doesnt matter which URL you give. It will still show a page (in browser) of that offset. I've asked a separate qn here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91868/mirroring-site-with-an-offset

Comment: Ha, so far for that URL being correct, @user13107 ;-)

Comment: @Arjan ya :). My browser does funny things.

Answer (score 10):

You can download the [entire Gutenberg collection of English books](http://download.kiwix.org/zim/gutenberg/gutenberg_en_all_2020-12.zim) and [of other languages](http://download.kiwix.org/zim/gutenberg/) in a single ZIM file, which is highly compressed and can then be opened with [Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/) both on desktop and Android. The English books are 40 GB.

## ZIM tools

Command line ZIM tools for Linux can be downloaded from:

https://download.openzim.org/release/zim-tools/

Comment: @aquagremlin Uh? http://www.kiwix.org/wiki/Software#GNU.2FLinux It's even packaged in some distros.

Comment: is this txt format book?

Comment: @A.D I'm not sure what you mean. It's text + images in HTML, packaged in ZIM rather than EPUB or other. You can get plain text out of it if you want, but my answer is mostly for people who prefer formatted books etc.

Comment: @Nemo How would I get the plain text out of a Zim file?

Comment: @cbracketdash it depends what you mean by plain text; you can use openzim to extract the HTML, which might have more formatting than you want.

Comment: What if I want the txt?

Answer (score 8):

**While the selected answer is correct, it will potentially cause two problems:**

1. You may receive a 403 error denying access to the pagination under the presumption you are downloading as a bot
2. There's the potential that you'll be sent to an external mirror, meaning the `wget` command will fail it's recursive checks on downloading the files from an external mirror.

**The below solution fixes these problems:**

```
wget -H -w 2 -m http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?filetypes[]=txt&langs[]=en \
--referer="http://www.google.com" \
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6" \
--header="Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5" \
--header="Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5" \
--header="Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" \
--header="Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" \
--header="Keep-Alive: 300"
```

You may want to change the referer and user-agent strings to provide a bit of randomness.

Answer (score 7):

ftp://mirrors.pglaf.org/mirrors/gutenberg-iso has a couple of good options.

ftp://mirrors.pglaf.org/mirrors/gutenberg-iso/pgdvd042010.iso is an 8GB file that should be sufficient for your needs.

There is more information here:

https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:The_CD_and_DVD_Project#Downloading_Via_FTP, it gives all the options of downloading the archive, including FTP and BitTorrent.

Comment: I recommend using a torrent as a more ethical option (on the same page as that third link): https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:The_CD_and_DVD_Project#Downloading_Via_BitTorrent It's more ethical because it puts less strain on Project Gutenberg's servers. It's probably faster and more effective, too. Plus, they recommend it over ftp. If you use Linux, Transmission is a good bit torrent client for the purpose. This will only give you books that existed on the site in 2010, however, but it seems the best option when shadowhorst's answer isn't functional.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the great tool at http://pgiso.pglaf.org/.

1. Enter an id range (e.g. 1-10000)
2. Select the desired file types
3. Choose the languages you want to include
4. Wait for the notification
5. Download

Comment: Not working for me, I can only see the raw php

Answer (score 2):

For access to all the plain text English books, I setup a private mirror as described in Project Gutenberg's [Mirroring Guide](https://www.gutenberg.org/help/mirroring.html). The ftp.ibiblio.org mirror worked with rsync:

```
mkdir $HOME/gutenberg
rsync -av --del ftp.ibiblio.org::gutenberg $HOME/gutenberg
```

To download *only* text files:

```
rsync -avm --include '*/' --include '*.txt' --exclude '*' --del ftp.ibiblio.org::gutenberg $HOME/gutenberg
```

Retrieving the file name listing will take anywhere from a few minutes to hours depending on Internet connection speed. After the file names have been retrieved, rsync will proceed to download all plain text files.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script which will download all (not just English) the ePub books files from the PG FTP server. It will take about 12 hours as the server connection is slow, and it'll be a ton of data. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/mxplusb/78363da5fe1e68a4e89d9fa8c720e034

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above answers, but none of them are resilient or fast. I would suggest using [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html).

```
httrack http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest\?filetypes\[\]\=txt\&langs\[\]\=en  -O "./guten" --mirrorlinks  -%v  "+aleph.gutenberg.org/*.zip" --continue
```

Answer (score -3):

Why not use all your over-complicated and shown above programming skills and knowledge to make a simple button that links all those actions and says "Download All Current Books" -with a language option tab when you click it.

I am sure most of the users that come to the site are e-book collectors, and manual downloading certain books on topics that interested them is OK for 1 or 2 books. But making a bigger collection manually is a drag. Nevertheless if they need it for research or would simply like to own a huge digital library of books at their own PC. Most people are turned off and scatter away from the site when they realize that they have to be a Computer Wizard to do this.So a "Download All Current Books" button would benefit the site the project and its users, and it will certainly produce even more visitors to the site. So that way everyone is happy.